# Error's with Powershell script to copy an .exe to a remote computer from a network share and installing the .exe

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to move a copy of the Google Earth Pro installer .exe from our network share to a remote computer. Here is what I have so far:

```
#Variable
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Computer Name"
$Destination = "\\$Computer\c$\Temp\GEP"

Copy-Item -Path "\\domain share path\software\google\google earth pro\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe" $Destination -Recurse
Write-Host "Installing Google Earth Pro"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
start-process "$Computer\c$\temp\GEP\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait
}
```

```
This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified. 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [StartProcess], InvalidOperationException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorID :InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand 
+ PSComputerName : "my computer name"
```

The latest error I get is that the system cannot find the file specified which Im not sure how that is possible since I copied the path from Windows Explorer.  I have administrator rights to our share and my PowerShell is running in Administrator mode.  What I want this script to do as a whole is the following:

1. Check if an older version of Google Earth Pro is currently installed
   1a. if yes, uninstall the older version
   1b. if not, proceed to copy-item
2. Copy the `exe` from our file share to the remote computer's c:\temp folder (creating GEP folder at the same time)
3. Install Google Earth Pro on the remote computer

Can anyone help?

PSA*
I cannot modify our GPO's due to security policy
I do not have a .msi installer

Comment: At which line or command is the error thrown? Looks like `start-process "$Computer\c$\temp\GEP\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe"` might land you in trouble, should probably be `start-process "c:\temp\GEP\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe"`, since it's already running on the remote machine

Comment: I doesn't provide a line number.  This is the whole error:
This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
      + CategoryInfo            : InvalidOperation: (:) [StartProcess], InvalidOperationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorID  : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
      + PSComputerName    : "my computer name"

Comment: Notice how it says `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand` and `"my computer name"` at the bottom? `my computer name\c$\temp\GEP\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe` is not a valid UNC path

Comment: Changed the path for the start-process to "c:\temp\GEP\googleearthpro v7.3.3-x64.exe".  It ran without an error.  Displayed "Installing Google Earth Pro Version 7.3.3.  Does not appear the transfer from the share happened.  File/Folder does not appear in TEMP folder on the remote machine

Comment: PLEASE, add your error text to the Question - and wrap it in code formatting so that it can be seen and read by all. [*grin*]

Comment: @MjrPayne - have you confirmed that your problem is NOT the classic "double hop" problem?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey There's no double-hop

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ah! thank you for the info ... i managed to misread the problem. [*blush*] should i kill that comment?

Comment: In addition to Mathias first comment. Even if you did intend to run it from the shared path, you are missing the leading slashes. Local path is what you want, just thought I'd toss this out there.